# jQuery: Returns only part of a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, text

I want to write a jQuery function that will return only a part of a given text. For example, in the text:

http://somesubdomain.somesite.com/

How can I write a function so that it returns the text "somesubdomain"? In other words, I want to "subtract" the text "http://" and ".somesite.com/".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getSubdomain() {
    var re = /http\:\/\/(\w+)\.somesite\.com\//;
    return (re(document.location)[1]);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused on why this the answer..... it has a param `domainString` that has not even used...

Comment: Well, the Regex works (I can't figure it out as I just starting to understand the regex concept). One question, though, what is the document.location doing there?

Comment: The regex (as explained, albeit briefly, in my answer as well), is 
a. Matches http://
b. Matches as many alpha numeric characters (i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9_]) characters after http:// as it can, so this will match somesubdomain, and remembering it in a backreference. Surrounding regex constructs in parenthesis makes it remember what was mathced. 
c) Finally it matches somesite.com/
The captured text (via backreference) is then being returned. 

For a good introduction to regular expressions checkout 

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, Jasmeet. So using a regex will create an array, the first one being the full url and the second one being "somesubdomain", but can't the third line just return (re[1]); ?

Comment: Line 2 defines the regex, line 3 applies the regex and then returns the captured text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a regex for this then the following (in Perl) should do it, assuming $str contains http://somesubdomain.somesite.com/

```
$str =~ s/http:\/\/([^.]+)\.somesite\.com\//$1/
print $str;
```

This prints somesubdomain.

Explanation - The regex captures somesubdomain from the string http://somesubdomain.somesite.com/ into the first back reference and then replaces the entire string with that.